# Can't make the keyboard show when focus is on EditText

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to show a Keyboard for a view as the focus is set to it once it renders. I tried multiple ways of trying to get it to work but whenever the Dialog renders and the focus is in the View, it doesn't show the keyboard until I click it.

This was one way I tried and it didn't work.

```
yieldEdit.RequestFocus();

imm = (InputMethodManager)(this.Activity).GetSystemService(AMSessionActivity.InputMethodService);
```

I then also tried to add an event to the view like so.

```
yieldEdit.FocusChange += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.HasFocus)
    {
        imm.ToggleSoftInput(ShowFlags.Forced, 0);
    }
};
```

This also doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure why it isn't working as it worked when it was an Activity.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using fragment or activity?

Comment: Using a Dialog Fragment. Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: See my updated answer @SmiffyKmc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code in EditText  xml;

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

and use the following to your activity

```
AMSessionActivity amsActivity = (AMSessionActivity) Activity;

yieldEdit.RequestFocus();

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)amsActivity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        imm.ShowSoftInput(yourTextBox, ShowFlags.Implicit);
```

Comment: This gives me errors on my screen. The getActivity() says "The name getActivity does not exist in this context" etc. So not sure what the story is with this.

Comment: getActivity() is used as Context in dialog fragment

Comment: That did it, my man! Thank you! I couldn't understand what I was doing wrong. Will accept!

Comment: I have one question for you. A keyboard comes up before I get to the Dialog which I want to keyboard to be in. But the first keyboard seems to override the Dialog one. How can I check if the keyboard is showing first to change it?

Answer (score -2):

Try to use :-

```
 editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            editText.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    editText.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay, but that looks like Java, It's C# Xamarin I'm looking for.